# Publisher URL vs Support URL in Windows installers

Tags: windows-installer

While polishing off an installer of mine, I noticed something weird in the Programs and Features dialog of Windows 7:

- *Publisher URL* is displayed as "Support link:"
- *Support URL* is displayed as "Help link:"

The problem seems ubiquitous: for most of my installed apps that supply these links, clicking "Support" takes me to the developer's website, and clicking "Help" takes me to their "Support" page.

[image: example]

Should I follow suit with my installer, or actually compensate for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this is totally up to you. I don't know about any policies / best practices being relied on that.

Answer (score 0):

Realize the links you pick must be forever ( distant echo: forever, forever, forever )

I'd set both the the same redirect URL that takes you to the product protal du jour. Or if you like, create two redirect URL's and then handle it there.  Once you ship you can't change what's in Add/Remove Programs but you can change your mind on where  your redirect's take you.